# What does 讲民主 mean?

Tags: word

My mandarin textbook says it means "speak to democracy," but I can't find a definition for this word anywhere on the internet. Even google translate says it is not a word.

Comment: @user3610: I reverted your edit. You seem to be answering the question, so please add an answer.

Comment: I am a native Chinese speaker and I don't know what it means exactly, maybe it means "(should) practice democracy"... I don't really know, but I guess it's close...

Comment: is there a word that somwhat means pay attention to democracy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

讲 here means:

> （讲求; 注重） stress; pay attention to; lay stress on; be particular about:

E. g. 讲吃讲穿; 讲交情;

In practice, we often say 讲文明，懂礼貌.

Comment: how come google translate doesn't have 讲民主? and is it used often?

Comment: @Wisesequoia I don't know why.  But 讲xxx overall is a common usage.

Answer (score 2):

It is not one word

> [讲](https://cantoneseplus.com/character/175) (v) speak

> 民主 (n) democracy

In Cantonese, the meaning for '讲' includes being the shorthand for 讲究 (pay attention to; regard); 讲求 (stress), = 注重; 追求

Example:

讲民主 (speak democracy) = regard/ pay attention to democracy

不讲民主 (speak democracy) = disregard/ not pay attention to democracy

讲道理 (speak reason) = reasonable

不讲道理 (not speak reason) = Unreasonable

香港人讲生活，讲享受 = "Hong Kong people pay attention to life and enjoyment"

Comment: can you give me a example in use?

Comment: @Wise sequoia It is mainly for Cantonese

Comment: 唔講道理 is closer to "unreasonable."  不 in Cantonese is closer in meaning to "forbid"

Comment: doesn't 民主 also mean freedom. My mom says people often use it to say let me have me own choice.

Comment: 民主 is a system, freedom is a state. You can be in a Democratic country and not being free if you are poor. Democracy may give some people freedom at the expense of others. Look at the last four years in US. Someone said Democracy is a bad governing system but it is currently the best we can have

Answer (score 0):

You should put the context in which you found this phrase, then the meaning would become apparent.

从理论上讲，他们的国家是一个多党派民主国家。
Theoretically, their nation is a multi-party democracy.

There's the rub: Maybe, in context, your "讲" holds the doubt expressed in "Theoretically"